# I am unable to change the center of a google map using a form's onSubmit property

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

My goal is to eventually allow a user to enter coordinates in two text boxes and then submitting the form to change the center of a google map with the new values. I am currently testing with simply having a button as part of the form. When the button is clicked a function with two hard coded values should change the center of the map but it is not working. The initial map is created correctly but then the center of the map does not change when the button is clicked. Here is my code for the javascript:

```
    var map;
    var center;
    var mapOptions;

    function reMap() {
     alert("setting the center");
     center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4200, -73.9550);
         map.setCenter(center);
         map.setZoom(10);
    }

    function initialize() {
     document.getElementById('location').onSubmit = reMap;

         mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
             zoom: 8,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); 

     }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and here is the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
         html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
          src="js/mapActions.js">
        </script>
      </head>
      <body >
      <div><form id="location" action="" method="post">
       <fieldset> <input type="submit" value="try" id="try"></fieldset></form></div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas as to why this is not working will be greatly appreciated. Note that if I change the input type to "button" and I add "onClick=reMap()" to the html then it actually works but like I mentioned I need to be able to use a form and I would rather not have function calls in the HTML. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A form's submit action will simply reload the emtire page.
Try this button, without any `<form>...</form>` tags:

```
<input type="button" value="Go to Chicago" id="chicago" onclick="function(){map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523))}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('location').onSubmit = reMap;
```

Change it to:

```
document.getElementById('location').onsubmit = reMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,your function named 'reMap()' assignment in initialize() seems to be wrong,

"document.getElementById('location').onSubmit = reMap;"

it should be onsubmit(), then it will be solved, else working fine.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Adding the "()" actually ended up calling the function inside initialize but just using "onsubmit" helped

Answer (score 0):

As Marcelo indicated, the form submit action will reload the page.  You say you can't (or don't want to use his proposed solution.  To prevent the submit action from reloading the page, the function needs to return "false".

Not tested:

```
function reMap() {
  // alert("setting the center");
  center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4200, -73.9550);
  map.setCenter(center);
  map.setZoom(10);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip, this with a combination of taking the capital off from onsubmit solved my problem